# How to use ANSI escape sequences with CSCRIPT on Windows 10?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, ansi-escape, wsh

I'm trying to use the new VT100 ANSI escape sequence capabilities available in the Windows 10 console with CSCRIPT (JScript). But I cannot get it to work.

Here is a really simple JScript script:

**test.js**

```
WScript.Echo('\x1B[7mReverse\x1B[0m Normal');
WScript.stdout.WriteLine('\x1B[7mReverse\x1B[0m Normal');
```

I've done a number of tests, and the escape sequences output by CSCRIPT are impotent when written directly to the screen, and only work if written to a file first and then TYPEed, or else captured by FOR /F and ECHOed.

[image]

I have two questions:

1) Why doesn't the direct write to the console work from CSCRIPT?
2) How can I get the direct write to work?

I would like to add text highlighting to my [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) (hence the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag), but I will not implement that feature if it requires a temporary file and/or FOR /F.

Comment: Did you try to pipe it through ' more '  or redirect it to  CON?

Comment: @jeb - The MORE test is already in the question (no help), and I also attempted redirecting to CON (not shown, and still no help). I found that it works fine if I run the test through [ANSICON,](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) either via pipe to ANSICON, or as ANSICON command line argument, or as command line command to an ANSICON process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx) states

> The following terminal sequences are intercepted by the console host
>   when written into the output stream if the
>   **ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING** flag is set on the screen buffer handle using the SetConsoleMode flag. You can use
>   GetConsoleMode and SetConsoleMode flags to configure this behavior.

So, just to test, I wrote a simple C program to change the console mode and then act as a pipe or launch another process and wait (sorry, just test code).

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING 0x0004

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]){

    // Console handlers
    DWORD dwOldMode, dwMode ;
    HANDLE hStdout;

    // Pipe read buffer
    int c;

    // Spawn process variables
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // Retrieve standard output handle
    hStdout = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    if (! GetConsoleMode( hStdout, &dwOldMode ) ) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Change standard output handle
    dwMode = dwOldMode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (! SetConsoleMode( hStdout, dwMode ) ){
        CloseHandle( hStdout );
        return 2;
    }

    if( argc < 2 ) {
        // If there is not an argument, read stdin / write stdout 
        while ( EOF != (c = getchar()) ) putchar( c );    
    } else {
        // Argument is present, create a process and wait for it to end
        ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
        if( !CreateProcess(NULL, argv[1], NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi )){
            printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
            return 3;
        }
        WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
        CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
        CloseHandle( pi.hThread );    
    }

    // Restore old console mode
    SetConsoleMode( hStdout, dwOldMode );
    CloseHandle( hStdout );

    return 0;
};
```

Compiled to `run.exe` with `mingw/gcc`. The results are

[image: Output capture of test session]

Now, the output from `cscript` and `findstr` is processed and the escape sequences are interpreted.

Also, if instead of running the separate programs, I run `cmd.exe` itself

[image: Output capture of redirected cmd.exe]

Since I have not changed the code from `findstr.exe`, `cscript.exe` or `cmd.exe`, only the environment where they are working it *seems* that

- neither `cscript` nor `findstr` configure/change the console buffer configuration
- some internal `cmd` commands change the buffer configuration (I forget to include it in the capture, but `copy test.txt con` and `prompt` also work) or, as you point, they use a different output method
- the only requirement for an application that writes to the standard output stream is that the console output buffer mode is properly configured.

And no, I don't know how to enable it from pure batch.

Comment: Yea!! I finally found a method to enable VT-100 for CSCRIPT (or any console app that doesn't disable it) in a SuperUser post. See my updated answer.

Comment: @dbenham, *"Yea!!"*, I have to agree with you. It seems there could be [some](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/892af39b-31e3-41e3-8328-5ac729a11fff/powershell-with-virtualterminallevel-in-recent-update-causes-crazy-tab-width?forum=winserverpowershell) side effects leaving it active, but it is a really nice finding and a new way to explore. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated Answer to part2: How to make it work in CSCRIPT

I finally found a mechanism to enable VT-100 sequences within CSCRIPT at [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/109090). I copied the relevant text from the answer and posted it below.

> Fortunately, the global default can be changed from *opt-in* to *opt-out*. The registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\VirtualTerminalLevel` sets the global default behavior for processing ANSI escape sequences. Create a `DWORD` key (if necessary) and set its value to `1` to globally enable (or `0` to disable`) ANSI processing by default.
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
> "VirtualTerminalLevel"=dword:00000001
> ```
>
> Note that this registry setting controls a *default*, meaning that it only affects console apps which don't explicitly manipulate the console mode by calling `SetConsoleMode(...)`. It follows that, while the registry value may help *enable* ANSI for *console-mode-oblivious* apps, it will have no effect on any *console-mode-savvy* app which (for some reason) may explicitly *disable* ANSI.

Note that the change only affects newly launched console windows - it will not enable VT-100 for already existing console windows.

---

Within [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9144), DosTips user aGerman discovered you can enable the escape sequences by asynchronously launching PowerShell from within your script. PowerShell configures the output to support the escape sequences, and that support remains even after PowerShell exits, for as long as your CSCRIPT process remains active.

For example, here is some JScript code that will enable the sequences

```
var ps = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("powershell.exe -nop -ep Bypass -c \"exit\"");
while (ps.Status == 0) WScript.Sleep(50);
```

### My original answer to part 1: Why doesn't it work in CSCRIPT

OK, I think I have a viable theory as to why it doesn't work. I believe that there must be some low level way/call/function/method (whatever) to pass stdout to the console that only a few internal commands know about. I base this on the fact that FINDSTR also cannot send functioning escape sequences to the console, as shown below:

[image]

I've already shown that both TYPE and ECHO work. I've also verified that SET /P works (not shown). So I suspect that cmd.exe was modified to support the new Windows 10 console functionality.

I would love to see some MS documentation describing the required mechanism to send escape sequences to the console.