# Print in cmd with colors using Python?

Tags: python, cmd, colors, pycharm

I am trying to color a string, but it doesn't work
I've tried this, but it doesn't work at the cmd window

```
print '\033[1;32mGreen like Grass\033[1;m'
```

Could someone tell me why?

In pycharm command window it does work

Comment: Works in my cmd window with Python3. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Could it be because your terminal doesn't support the escape sequence?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39410032/2861476) could provide more information.

Comment: Further information might be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420992/colorize-console-output-in-intellij-products

Comment: i use windows not linox

Comment: im using python 2.7.6

Comment: it is also not working in the idle shell

Comment: Just use `fish` shell.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to do with your terminal settings. When I run

```
python -c "print('\033[1;32mGreen like Grass\033[1;m')"
```

I get a green string. What value does your TERM environment variable have?

```
echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

On Linux [the `termcap` program](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html) handles terminal capabilities. You  may just need to match TERM setting to your actual terminal emulator.

Comment: it is also not working in the idle shell